# How can I start python console from Windows cmd after Anaconda Platform has been upgraded?

Tags: python, anaconda

I know this sounds like a noob question but I'm not sure where to look nor what to look for.

Before upgrading Anaconda's Platform I was able to open a Windows command prompt, type "python" and then start my scripting on console. But now that I've upgraded Anaconda, when I type "python" I only get a message showing the python and Anaconda versions.

[Message shown by console after typing "python"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82PgD.jpg)

I've set my PATH environment variable to

```
...AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda
```

as it was before the upgrade, I've even navigated to that same path and tried running the python file from there and still got just the message.

I have pycharm installed, and my projects interpreter is set to that same directory but it says the python version is 2.7.9 while the version shown in console is 2.7.13.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `which python` will give you the path of python.exe that runs python on your console. While in Pycharm, it is up to Project Interpreter setting.
If what you get from `which python` is not the one you want, type in the full path of the python.exe you want, or change directory to its folder and run.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm on windows so I've installed cygwin to run "which python" command and... it gives me the same directory I already have in my PATH. Still I'm not able to start my happy scripting in windows cmd by typing "python", it only gives me the current python and anaconda versions :/

Comment: There could be several paths to `python.exe` defined with your PATH, the first one will run. Try type in the full path of the one you want. Or cd to its directory  and execute it.

Comment: I already tried that... I've typed the full path where the python.exe file es and still nothing... A friend of mine had the exact same problem, he's going to help me with it, I'll post what he did as long as I know. Thanks for your help :)